# How to use libpng with OpenGL for a 2D game?

Tags: objective-c, c, opengl, libpng

I am beginning with OpenGL, and I want to make a very simple game with airplanes. Now I have a PNG of an airplane seen from above, and I want to draw this on the screen. Currently I only know how to draw triangles that rotate:

```
float angle = 0.0f;
void renderScene(void) {
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glPushMatrix();
  glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
  glVertex2f(-0.5,-0.5);
  glVertex2f(0.5,0.0);
  glVertex2f(0.0,0.5);
  glEnd();
  glPopMatrix();
  glutSwapBuffers();
  angle += 0.1;
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is your stash of secrets: http://nehe.gamedev.net/

By the way you will end up drawing a quad (or a triangle strip) and applying the texture onto the polygon, nothing so complicated.. but start in a precise way by looking at tutorials and understanding how OpenGL works, it would be better.

This book will be better than Nehe (since it's tailored exactly for OpenGL ES): http://opengles-book.com/

Comment: I'm using just OpenGL, not OpenGL ES. NeHe is quite cool. I'll check it out.

Comment: Oh sorry, my assumption derived from the objective-c tag. I supposed you were working on the iPhone :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using libpng directly, you might want to consider using [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/). It's intended specifically for the kind of job you seem to be trying to do so it'll generally make it quite a bit easier to do (and next month, when somebody decides you should display a JPEG or maybe a TIFF instead of a PNG, it'll handle that without any major rewrite either).